# How do I set a required length to an integer in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement

How do I allow the user to re enter the customerID number if it does not match 5 digits in length?

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter the 5-digit ID number of your customer "
                + (i + 1) + "'s below:");
        customerID[i] = myScanner.nextLine();

        if (customerID[i].length() != 5) {
            // What code goes here. I just want to make it so they can
            // re-enter the customerID
        }
```

Comment: `--i; continue;` I guess. But I would use a `do { read line; } while (line length != 5);` instead.

Comment: You can already read user-input, so what exactly is the question ? How you copy-paste your code to re-ask for input ? How to create a while loop to keep asking until the input meets the requirements ?

Comment: Your title is very misleading, given the actual question.

Comment: My question is really how to create a while loop to keep asking until the input meets the requirments (of 5 digits long)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
while(true)
{
    customerID[i] = myScanner.nextLine();
    if(customerID[i].length() == 5) break;
    System.out.print("Should be of length 5! Try Again: ");
}
```

Comment: You can break for a label, but not continue.  You can add `while(true)` at the start and `break;` at the end.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Yes, that's what I did. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

(Maybe) the shortest solution for this:

```
do
{
    customerID[i] = myScanner.nextLine();
} while(customerID[i].length() != 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the loop you have.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    System.out.println("Enter the 5-digit ID number of your customer "
            + (i + 1) + "'s below:");
    customerID[i] = myScanner.nextLine();

    if (customerID[i].length() != 5) {
        // What code goes here. I just want to make it so they can
        // re-enter the customerID

        i--; // add this.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead. Basically you don't have to increment the index until you have a valid input.

```
int i = 0;
while( i < 5 ) {
 System.out.println("Enter the 5-digit ID number of your customer "
 + (i + 1) + "'s below:");
 customerID[i] = myScanner.nextLine();

 if (customerID[i].length() != 5) {
     /* Print an error and do not increment. 
      * The next line will overwrite the current one. */
 } else {
     /* Increment and move on */
     i++;
 }
}
```